# get the "FROM" field using Facebook Graph Api on comments for a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, comments

first of all, i own the page and i'm the only admin
so i have to get the access_token of my page (after the last update of facebook) :

```
/{page_id}?fields=access_token
```

so this is the url i'm using to get the information of my desired comment:

```
/{comment_id}?fields=id,from,message&access_token=my-page-token
```

and still, the response is showing only the id and the message.
i don't know how to access the user information 
i'm using the access token to do so as mentionned in the facebook api docs and i own the page
what am i missing?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi all, having same issue . any solution

Comment: Hello guys, since Mark's interview about clients' data use .. you can no longer get other users' information ..

Comment: Try to follow the instructions as mentioned here in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76549200/12326605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the latests update in the Graph API, to get private information from the users, even the author of some public post. You need to get the auth token with the manage_pages scope to get permission to the page itself then get the app reviewed ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review ) and last you must go thru the Business Verification or the Individual Verification.
The last is a legal contract to use the info.

After that something else. You have to ask the page-specific access token. That is in the /me/accounts , that will give you a list of pages that has given you access. One of the fields is access-token or something like that. With that token you must ask for the comments with the FORM field.

Here I explain the details:
[Facebook Graph API: How do I get “from” field in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959703/facebook-graph-api-how-do-i-get-from-field-in-comment/56169760#56169760)