# Facebook Graph API: How do I get “from” field in comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook App which wasn't published(test mode).
I used the Page Access Token to extract the 'from' field from comments in a particular post on the my own Page. But it return empty field.

This is my Graph API Query
=> /[post-id]/comments?fields=from

When I checked the Page Access Token with the token debugger, It had    'manage_pages, pages_show_list, public_profile' permissions.

How do I get the 'from' field from comments in my own Page ?
Do I need to complete the app review or do I need special permission to do this(like Page Public Content Access) ?

Comment: You still have this problem. I don't think so. Just recheck properly in Graph API.

Answer (score 2):

Since the latest update in the Graph API, to get private information from the users, even the author of some public post. You need to get the auth token with the manage_pages scope to get permission to the page itself then get the app reviewed ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review ) and last you must go thru the Business Verification or the Individual Verification. The last is a legal contract to use the info.

That's for live use. The "from" field must be acquired with the PAGE ACCESS TOKEN. To get that token first you must have the USER ACCESS TOKEN. Then make a request to

```
GET /v3.2/me/accounts
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "access_token": "some_big_string",
        "category": "Health/Beauty",
        "category_list": [
            {
                "id": "2214",
                "name": "Health/Beauty"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Page_Name",
        "id": "5648645556490",
        "tasks": [
            "ANALYZE",
            "ADVERTISE",
            "MODERATE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MANAGE"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, to get the "from" filed you must use the token for that specific page, that is the "access_token" field in the request made above. This one is a specific PAGE ACCESS TOKEN. The other one is a USER ACCESS TOKEN.