# Facebook Graph Api: What permission is needed to get authors of comments of page posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I run a FB page, and I would like to mirror its content on a website.
I am able to get page posts and comments, but for the comments, I am not able to get a `from` field - when I query it, there is no error, but the field doesn't appear in returned data, so I can see just a texts of comments, but not their authors.

This seems weird to me, as I think comment author is a public info - on FB, everyone can look at my public FB page, and see both comments and their authors.

**What I did:**

1. Created a fb app (to be able to get a token with page access)
2. In Graph API Explorer I selected `Facebook App`: my app, `User or Page`: my page, `Permissions`: `pages_show_list`, `pages_read_engagement`, `pages_read_user_content`
3. I ran query `<my page id>/posts?fields=from,icon,full_picture,is_hidden,likes,reactions,comments{from,id,created_time,message,likes}`

**What happens:**

I got posts, but only with `id`,`message` fields (no `from` field)

**What I expected to happen**

I expected to know who wrote the comments.

Is there a permission I am missing? Or is there some limitation of FB API I don't know about?

**Edit:** I found a post stating that I must pass a review and verification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56169760/38729

Comment: any luck with this, i am trying to post photo in a page with similar issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704658/unable-to-post-on-facebook-photos-to-groups-and-pages-via-graph-api

Comment: I am getting stuck with this problems as well. Seems like Facebook changed something and it is not possible to get the user who posted the comment...

Comment: you need pages_manage_engagement scope for it