# unable to post on facebook photos to groups and pages via graph-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

my app is in development

i am using below permissions:
"public_profile",
"publish_video",
"pages_show_list",
"pages_read_engagement",
"pages_manage_posts",
"publish_pages",
"user_managed_groups",
"groups_show_list",
"publish_to_groups",
"groups_access_member_info",
"publish_actions"

but on trying use the api to post photo in group and page i get below errors

[https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{page-id}/photos?access_token=={token}&url={url.jpg}](https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/%7Bpage-id%7D/photos?access_token==%7Btoken%7D&url=%7Burl.jpg%7D)

error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "AW4L8qJL7HJWz9oTL7rk1IY"
}
}
```

[https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{group-id}/photos?access_token={token}&url={url.jpg}](https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/%7Bgroup-id%7D/photos?access_token=%7Btoken%7D&url=%7Burl.jpg%7D)

error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) Insufficient permission to post to group",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "AsV2H45AICb6G7D73aiedW4"
}
}
```

Can someone please help with this

Answer (score 0):

Solution for page post

follow this url for details: [access_token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/)

using user access token get page access token, pass this page access token in above url for page post

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{page-id}?access_token={user-access-token}&fields=access_token'
```