# How to get from field of a facebook comment using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am using the comment-id to get the from field and using the page access token:

```
[comment-id]?fields=from&access_token=[PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

But I am not getting the desired output, I am getting back the comment-id only

```
{
  "id": "[comment-id]"
}
```

I am not getting what mistake I am making here.

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{pagepost-id}_{comment-id}` format instead.

Example Request:-

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/222277054012345_979370980112345?access_token=<YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Response:-

```json
{
  "created_time": "2023-06-25T06:25:41+0000",
  "from": {
    "name": "John doe",
    "id": "111282025112345"
  },
  "message": "This is to explore FB comment API.",
  "id": "222277054012345_979370980112345"
}
```

Additionally, To get all the comments made on a Facebook page post you can use the following API call:-

Request:-

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/111282025112345_222277054012345/comments?access_token=<YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Here in the URL, 111282025112345 is `page_id` and 222277054012345 is `post_id`.

Response:-

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2023-06-25T06:25:41+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "John doe",//Comment Author's name
        "id": "111282025112345"//Comment Author's id
      },
      "message": "This is to explore FB comment API.",
      "id": "222277054012345_979370980112345" //`{pagepost-id}_{comment-id}`
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MgZDZD",
      "after": "MQZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.